# atoi function adds number from buffer

Tags: c, buffer, concatenation, atoi

I tried to take 2 integers (smaller than 40000) between a blank like `1232 11232` and then parse it to integer. As you can understand `getfirstnum` returns the first number. But the problem is that there is something unusual I couldn't understand. When I type `11232 22312` as an input the output must be same `11232 22312` but it is `2231211232 223121232`. it basically puts the second number in front of first number, it concatenates both numbers and in second one it concatenate the last 4 digits. Why and how to solve it?

PS: I get input with regex to get input with blank (blank is problem in `scanf`) it clearly works, I checked it many times. Problem starts in `atoi` because before `atoi` the string is parsed well.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int getfirstnum(char *input);
int getsecnum(char *input);

int main() {
    char *input = malloc(40005 * sizeof(char));
    int N, target, i = 0, j = 0, x, y, shot = 0, found = 0;

    scanf(" %[^\n]s", input);

    N = getfirstnum(input);
    target = getsecnum(input);

    printf("%d %d", N, target);
}

int getfirstnum(char *input) {
    int numm, i = 0;
    char num1[40005];

    while (input[i] != ' ') {
        num1[i] = input[i];
        i++;
    }
    fflush(stdout);
    numm = atoi(num1);
    return numm;
}

int getsecnum(char *input) {
    int num, i = 0, j = 0;
    char num2[40005];

    while (input[i] != ' ')
        i++;

    i++;

    while (i < strlen(input)) {
        num2[j] = input[i];
        printf("%c", sayi2[j]);
        i++;
        j++;
    }
    num = atoi(num2);

    return num;
}
```

Comment: What is this `fflush(stdout);`  doing in `getfirstnum()`? And please really format the code.

Comment: I'd start properly indenting my code first.

Comment: beacuse i thought there is a buffer problem, it holds the second and first number and concatenate it. That's why i but fflush but it doesnt effect anything. before fflush problem was same and it didn't change anything.

Comment: Your `scanf()` is wrong, unless your line of numbers always ends with an `s`.

Comment: it really gets the string clearly. I checked it million time. You can check it too. Just copy scanf and the input declaration.

Comment: Since you're not even checking the return value of `scanf()`, and the literal `s` is the last part of your format string, you won't notice the error, but I assure you you don't know how `%[]` works for `scanf()`.

Comment: thanks "user3121023". it really worked.

Comment: `char num1[40005];`  Do you really expect to parse numbers with 40004 digits?  Made me day!

Comment: actually now i get segmentation fault. it gets until 3 digits. when i type 5 digit 2 numbers as an input like "12311 11232" it crahes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code shows major confusion between the number value and the number of digits. Your code fails because you do not null terminate the buffers after copying digits from the source. But your code is way too complicated for the task: parsing numbers can be done easily with `sscanf()` or `strtol()`.  All you need is a buffer to read one line:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char line[256];
    int N, target;

    if (fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin)) {
        if (sscanf(line, "%d%d", &N, &target) == 2) {
            printf("%d %d\n", N, target);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Or using `strtol`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    char line[256];
    int N, target;
    char *p, *q;

    if (fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin)) {
        N = strtol(line, &p, 10);
        target = strtol(p, &p, 10);
        if (p > line && q > p)
            printf("%d %d\n", N, target);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: oh yeah. I tried but i couldn't because of reputation. But now yep i did. Thanks. And if you dont mind i have additional one more question. When i try to define an 2 dimensional array with N like "int arr[N][N];" it gives an error et the end of the program. I used your sscanf version. But when i declare the array, it crashes in declareation line.

Comment: You cannot define such a 2D array locally if `N` is large, such as `40000` because it uses more memory than is available for the stack.  Allocate it with `malloc` this way:  `int (*arr)[N] = malloc(sizeof(int) * N * N);`

Comment: if i could, i would give you double upvotes :D thanks a lot. Everything is clear right now.

Answer (score 0):

Silly mistake :)

Your debugging statements for num2 caused the confusion.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
int getfirstnum(char *input);
int getsecnum(char *input);

int main(){
    char *input = malloc(40005 * sizeof(char));
    int N, target, i = 0, j = 0, x, y, shot = 0, found = 0;

    scanf(" %[^\n]s", input);

    N = getfirstnum(input);
    target = getsecnum(input);


    printf("%d %d", N, target);
}

int getfirstnum(char *input){
    int numm, i = 0;
    char num1[40005];

    while (input[i] != ' '){
        num1[i] = input[i];
        i++;
    }
    num1[i] = '\0';  /* null terminate string */

    fflush(stdout);
    numm = atoi(num1);
    return numm;
}

int getsecnum(char *input){
    int num, i = 0, j = 0;
    char num2[40005];

    while (input[i] != ' ')
        i++;

    i++;

    printf("debugging of num2\n");  /* your statements without newline... */
    while (i<strlen(input)){
        num2[j] = input[i];
        printf("%c", num2[j]);
        i++;
        j++;
    }
    num2[j] = '\0';  /* null terminate string */
    printf("end debugging of num2\n");  

    num = atoi(num2);

    return num;
}
```

... attention to detail...

Comment: actually it was one mistake. but as you know there is problem with num1 although there is no debug printf for num1. what  user3121023 said was okay. all i need is putting '\0' at the end of char arrays to make them string so atoi can work properly. It is not a SILLY mistake, it was just a string-char arrray problem.

Comment: @AngusComber: I'm afraid your correction does not address the issue. `num1` and `num2` must be null terminated (with `num1[i] = '\0';` and `num2[j] = '\0';`) before passing them to `atoi`.

Comment: Agreed - but in his printout that wasn't the problem.  Added to above code.